# Template signature problem

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to using templates and am required to use a template to do something, but don't know how to call the templated function. It's probably soething simple, but I can't see it.

```
template<class It, class T>


// iterator and value_type of *It
void Calc(It begin, It end, std::pair<int, int> &out)
{
        std::vector<It>::iterator iter;
    std::map<int, int> StartMap;
    std::map<int, int>::reverse_iterator rit;

    int sum, start, stop, count;
    start = stop = 1;
    count = sum = 0;

    for(iter = begin; iter != end; iter++ )
    {
        sum += iter;
        count++;
        stop++;
        if(sum <= 0)
        {
            // store original start
            StartMap.insert(start, count);
            // set new start position
            start = stop;
        }   
    }

    // set iterator to highest value
    rit = StartMap.rbegin();

    start = rit->first;
    stop = start + rit->second;

    out.insert(start, stop);
}
```

but not sure how I call it with 2 std::vector iterators.
I've tried this

```
void doSomething(std::vector<int>& stopsVec)
{
    std::pair<int, int> out;
    Calc<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::pair<int, int>>(stopsVec.begin(), stopsVec.end(), &out);
}
```

Comment: you don't appear to be using the template parameter `T` at all.

Comment: What error are you getting that you think your issue is calling the function?

Answer (score 4):

```
void doSomething(std::vector<int>& stopsVec)
{
    std::pair<int, int> out;
    Calc<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::pair<int, int> >
        (stopsVec.begin(), stopsVec.end(), out);   // not &out
}
```

`Calc` takes a reference to `std::pair<int, int>`, so you want to just give it `out`.  Passing `&out` tries to pass a pointer to a pair - which won't work.

**EDIT**

assuming the signature is actually:

```
template<class It>
void Calc(It begin, It end, std::pair<int, int> &out)
```

You can call it with:

```
Calc(stopsVec.begin(), stopsVec.end(), out);
```

The compiler can deduce the correct template type from the parameters, without requiring you to specify them between `<>`

**EDIT**

Keith makes a good point below.  That's another compilation error you would have here.  Also note that:

```
sum += iter;
```

does not do what you want.  you probably meant:

```
sum += *iter;
```

But since `sum` is an int, and `iter` is a template type, this is not really a general-purpose template method.  It's really only going to work for iterators over numeric types.

And, one other issue:

```
Calc<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::pair<int, int> >  // use a space
    (stopsVec.begin(), stopsVec.end(), out);
```

instead of

```
Calc<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::pair<int, int>>  // ">>" is shift operator
    (stopsVec.begin(), stopsVec.end(), out);
```

You need a space between the closing `>` signs in order to have template syntax.  Otherwise you're doing bitshift (or stream extraction), and the compiler will get confused because nothing will make sense from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

```
template<class It, class T>
void Calc(It begin, It end, std::pair<int, int> &out)
{
    std::vector<It>::iterator iter;
    for(iter = begin; iter != end; iter++ )
```

is wrong. It should probably be:

```
template<class It, class T>
    void Calc(It begin, It end, std::pair<int, int> &out)
    {
        It iter;
        // etc.
        for(iter = begin; iter != end; iter++ )
```

But also note that in C++, it is generally preferred to follow the 'declaration is initialisation' approach, so this becomes:

```
  template<class It, class T>
        void Calc(It begin, It end, std::pair<int, int> &out)
        {
             // etc.
            for(It iter = begin; iter != end; iter++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly pass the type being iterated over as a template argument.  The STL designers were quite wise and realized that this often comes up, and there's a (not very pretty but entirely correct) way to introspect on the type of an iterator to get it's underlying type as follows:

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type value_type;
```

Once you've done this, you can use the name value_type to refer to the type being iterated over.  This lets you rewrite the template function as

```
template <typename It>
void Calc(It begin, It end, std::pair<int, int>& out) {
     typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type value_type;
     /* ... Rest of the code, now using this type ... */
}
```

And to seal the deal, now that there aren't any auxiliary types required, you can call the function directly as

```
std::vector<int> v = /* ... */
std::pair<int, int> result;
Calc(v.begin(), v.end(), result);
```

Hopefully this is easier to read and write!